# Chrome with QUIC enabled is making TLS connection to first Google search result

Tags: chrome, quic

When I search a site by its name on Google search engine, my Chrome browser pings the first search result, making a TLS connection.
For example, if I search "github" on Google, the first result displayed is obviously github.com, and I can see with my firewall a connection to github.com:443 (before clicking the result).
This connection is not displayed in Inspector > Network.
This happens only with QUIC enabled (default). The same happens with local websites too, for example if I search "automobili", the first result is "automobili.it" and I see a connection to automobili.it:443
It doesn't happen if search results display on top a Google Maps or News.
What is this?

Comment: This is probably [link prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Link_prefetching_FAQ).

Comment: This may give company information on how many times it was searched and shown as first result, with IP of visitor. Strange it isn’t shown in Inspector, it seems a leak of PII.